# Foundation db Python client bidding version

Tags: foundationdb

I'm getting the following exception when I use python binding. I thought client binding apis are backward compatible. If not how/where can I get the python library corresponding to the version 610

```
  fdb.api_version(610)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fdb/__init__.py", line 76, in api_version
    "%d, but the installed library supports a maximum version of %d." % (header_version, max_supported_ver))
RuntimeError: This version of the FoundationDB Python binding is not supported by the installed FoundationDB C library. The binding requires a library that supports API version 620, but the installed library supports a maximum version of 610.
```

Answer (score 1):

The host from where you are running the python client also needs to have the foundation db client installed.

For example for 6.2.20 on Ubuntu the download link for client is [here](https://www.foundationdb.org/downloads/6.2.20/ubuntu/installers/foundationdb-clients_6.2.20-1_amd64.deb).

Answer (score -1):

For version 610 you need to install `foundationdb` version 6.1.XX (I used 6.1.11). You can update the foundationdb package you already installed with

`pip install -I foundationdb==6.1.11`

The `-I` will replace whatever installed version you have with the one you are about to install.